# Does Windows EventLog drops off old items as new items are added?

Tags: windows-10, event-log, event-viewer

Does the Windows EventLog automagically truncate or drop off items ? (Windows 10 Pro).
[image]
Refer to my screenshot. First item shown is 15/3/2019 at 7:32:12 PM

When i first looked at the log I am absolutely sure the starting time was approx 6:35 PM; Then about 6 hours later when i looked at it again, some rows had drooped off, and the starting time was approx 7:00 PM, and now the latest view shows 7:32.12 PM

I did not filter any items, or clear the log in any way. Is this a "feature" of Windows ?

**NOTE:** From the moment I started writing the question, about 10 mins have passed. I refreshed again and a few more items have dropped off,  first item in the log is now 7:34:19 PM. What's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer. Indeed it does clear items BY DEFAULT ! Bad default if you ask me.

[image: EventLog properties]

Comment: It's actually not bad. Think about it: the only alternatives are to either 1) Stop logging new events once the log reaches its size limit (and if you next need the log 3 years later you will discover there's nothing remotely recent in the log, making it utterly worthless), or 2) Allow the log to grow until it fills the disk (causing your server to crash). Neither is acceptable as a default.

Comment: Really? what about once the log file reaches a certain size, stop logging to it, but start logging to a new file. It's then up to the user to determine why s/he is running out of disk space.

Comment: Many systems are expected to run unattended for long periods of time. Such a configuration would *guarantee* the system's disk space would eventually be exhausted. On systems with limited disk space or high log activity, this would happen rapidly. That's **not** a good design choice.

Comment: So it's a good choice to drop off and loose event records, never to be recovered again, without any prior warning to an unsuspecting user ?

Comment: Given that said unsuspecting user's alternative option is a system that will not boot, I say yes.

Comment: Any sane systems will do some kind of log rotation like that. For example Ubuntu keeps 4 weeks of log by default. See [For how long Linux system logs are stored?](https://askubuntu.com/q/910546/253474). The oldest entry will be cleared, otherwise what happens if the log becomes huge? Even if it writes to a new file then at some point there must be someone to clear the old files, or do you intend to leave it to infinity? Who needs to read a log a year ago anyway?

Comment: "Bad default if you ask me"- thank god they didn't ask you